# Arba'a Vetish'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred ninety-four?

### ?ארבעה ותשעים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 294.

This is not a great region on the number line for lazy gematriot.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred ninety-three entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: As we are coming into Shabbos Mevorchim Nissan, 294 is the Gematria of "לחיים לחיים לחיים" for the four cups of whine which we will be drinking. However, as we are close to purim we forgot how to count and therefore only mention 3 (or if we remove a kollel from the amount of cups drunk).

Comment: But then, what does kollel have to do with the seder? I guess we will have to add a question to the four questions. And that will also take care of the kollel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 14 possible Jewish calendar combinations. In a year where the following combination happens  - זש"ג - there are **294** days that are not Shabbos or Yom Tov (Chutz L'Aretz) and you may do Melacha.

An explanation of what זש"ג mean.

- The first letter is the day of the week that Rosh HaShana comes out on.
- The second letter tells you whether Cheshvon and Kisleiv have both 29 days = (ח) for Chasair. If Cheshvon has 29 days and Kisleiv has 30 days then = (כ) for K'Sidran. If both Chesvan and Kisleiv have 30 days then = (ש) for Shlaima.
- The third letter is the day of the week that Pesach comes out on.

Comment: +1, Where'd you find this?

Answer (score 1):

According to various sources available via Google Books, in 1279, 294 Jews were executed in Britain on charges of [coin-clipping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_coin_debasement).

Answer (score 0):

[According to Encyclopaedia Judaica](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0006_0_06088.html), 294 Jews in [Essen-Steele](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steele,_Germany) were deported to [Theresienstadt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theresienstadt_concentration_camp) on July 21, 1942.